# Autolayout VFL and margins

Tags: ios, autolayout, margins

Having a few issues with Autolayout and defining it using VFL.

I have a UILabel and UIImage in code, I want to align them both to the top of the container. Everything works OK, except for the UILabel, which has padding at the top which I cannot get rid of.

I'm using a very simple VFL string: "V:|-(0)-[labelView]" and "V:|-(0)-[imageView]"

The imageView works as it should, but labelView has padding which I cannot get rid of.

[image: AL Problem]

Is there a margin or padding setting that I can turn off?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did a bit of research, and thanks to the graphic in this link: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/02/understanding-uifont/ , I was able to work out a solution.

Subclass UILabel and override drawTextInRect with the following:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
   CGFloat topInset = self.font.ascender - self.font.descender - self.font.capHeight;

   UIEdgeInsets insets = {-topInset, 0, 0, 0};

   return [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking to solve similar problems! :-)